# Sql query if is null

Tags: sql

I need help to return a result if value exists or no.

**UPDATED:** The image show where I need help:

[image: Problem SQL]

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s im sorry, im posting from the app mobile. I mean I should get the column names but with that results

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `CASE EXPRESSION` with a `LEFT JOIN` .

I didn't fully understand the output you expect, but just add the columns you want:

```
@in_myvar = 11
select bt.username,at.postid,
       CASE WHEN ct.userid is null the 0 else 1 end as c_ind
from A at
INNER JOIN B bt
 ON (at.userid = bt.userid and bt.userid = @in_myvar)
LEFT JOIN C ct
 ON(ct.userid = at.userid)
```

Comment: @Jorge Did you try my query? This should do what you want!

Comment: Hey, yes but I just notice that don't work if I use 2 vars as in the image above, may can you help me with that?

Comment: `b.username` and `a.postid` are wrong in the select list as you have used different aliases from tables A and B.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Z7Z.png in this query i dont see any error besided where i need to help

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
declare @in_myvar int = 11
select B.username,A.postid,(Case when C.postid = A.postid then 1 Else 0 end) as UserExists
from A inner join B on A.userID = B.UserID
Left Join C 
On C.userID = A.userID
where B.userID = @in_myvar
```

Comment: This is the same answer as mine !

Comment: Yeah I noticed it later. Didn't see yours before posting my answer. It's a tiny bit different though.

Answer (score 0):

You want a result row for each record in A. So select from A. The data from the other tables can be got with subqueries:

```
select
  (select username from b where b.userid = a.userid) as username,
  a.postid,
  case when exists (select * from c where c.userid = a.userid) then 1 else 0 end as has_c
from a;
```

As B:A = 1:n, you can also join B, if you like that better:

```
select
  b.username,
  a.postid,
  case when exists (select * from c where c.userid = a.userid) then 1 else 0 end as has_c
from a
join b on b.userid = a.userid;
```